# R - repetition with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rep

To transform my "long compact" format data into wide format, I need to use the `rep` function.

I cannot figure out how to integrate it into a `dplyr` flow.

This is the repetition I need to use:

```
dta1 = as.data.frame(cbind(rep(dta$id, dta$duration), rep(dta$act, dta$duration) ) ) 
colnames(dta1) <- c('id', 'act')
```

Here is the `dplyr` code.

```
dta1 %>%
group_by(id) %>% 
mutate(Time = 1:n() ) %>%
spread(Time, act)
```

Do you have any idea how could I put these two codes together?

The data

```
dta = structure(list(id = c("B10001N1", "B10001N1", "B10001N1", "B10001N1", 
                  "B10001N1", "B10001N1", "B10001N1", "B10001N1", "B10001N1", "B10001N1", 
                  "B10001N1", "B10001N1", "B10001N1", "B10001N1", "B10001N1", "B10001N1", 
                  "B10001N2", "B10001N2", "B10001N2", "B10001N2", "B10001N2", "B10001N2", 
                  "B10001N2", "B10001N2", "B10001N2", "B10001N2", "B10001N2", "B10001N2", 
                  "B10001N2", "B10001N3", "B10001N3", "B10001N3", "B10001N3", "B10001N3", 
                  "B10001N3", "B10001N3", "B10001N3", "B10001N3", "B10001N3", "B10001N3", 
                  "B10001N3", "B10001N3", "B10001N4", "B10001N4", "B10001N4", "B10001N4", 
                  "B10001N4", "B10001N4", "B10001N4", "B10001N4", "B10001N4", "B10001N4", 
                  "B10001N4", "B10001N4", "B10001N4"), act = c("-11", "1704", "1302", 
                                                               "1301", "1507", "603", "1301", "101", "502", "1704", "1507", 
                                                               "1404", "8888", "603", "1507", "101", "-11", "1302", "1301", 
                                                               "1507", "704", "101", "1704", "1704", "3102", "1002", "1704", 
                                                               "3101", "101", "-11", "1704", "1302", "1302", "1507", "603", 
                                                               "2902", "3201", "812", "1704", "1704", "3701", "101", "-11", 
                                                               "1302", "1301", "3101", "1001", "1507", "1006", "2101", "2902", 
                                                               "1704", "8888", "1704", "1302"), duration = c(30, 570, 5, 30, 
                                                                                                             25, 3, 12, 165, 30, 10, 5, 20, 70, 45, 180, 240, 570, 30, 30, 
                                                                                                             20, 25, 95, 70, 20, 20, 20, 60, 45, 435, 30, 30, 570, 90, 30, 
                                                                                                             15, 5, 40, 60, 240, 60, 30, 240, 600, 15, 45, 15, 75, 30, 150, 
                                                                                                             60, 30, 60, 210, 60, 90)), row.names = c(NA, 55L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("id", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "act", "duration"))
```

Comment: Why not just `dta[rep(1:nrow(dta), dta$duration), -3] %>% ...`?

Comment: great - can you put it as an answer that I can close the question ? thanks

Comment: A similar approach with `splitstackshape/data.table(v1.9.5)` `dcast(setDT(expandRows(dta, 'duration'))[, Time := 1:.N, ,id], id~Time,value.var='act')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dta[rep(1:nrow(dta), dta$duration), -3] %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate( Time = 1:n() ) %>%
  spread(Time, act)
```

Comment: great solution! +1. I am bit puzzled as to why the OP's approach is significantly faster than the proposed solution. Would you mind giving an insight?

Comment: Good point. Seems to be more readable, but less efficient in this case due to much bigger memory allocation. However, I do not know how R stuff works under the hood.

Comment: It is a little bewildering that such an elegant approach is slow. Fortunately, just found that the same subsetting operation on `data.table` is much faster.